# Changing Colours on Tables with Hover Effect

Tags: html, css, wordpress, if-statement

I'm currently working on a wordpress website. I want on the landing page different boxes which all link to different sub-pages. I used tables to create those boxes. Further, I added a hover effect so when you mouse-over any of those boxes/tables, the background will turn to blue and the font to white.

there's one header and one row (single column) per box/table. The header font should be blue, the row font should be black (when not applying the hover effect). I managed to put the hover effect on header and row separately but now I need the if else condition so whenever you mouse-over the header (the header font turning to white, background colour turning to blue), the row should have the hover effect, too (font turning to white, background colour turning to blue), and vice-versa. I haven't done any programming for ages so I'm a bit lost with the if else condition. Can anyone help me there? Any solution would be greatly appreciated.

Code for the table:

```
<div class="table-3"><a title="website" href="website">
<table width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><hr style="border: 1px solid;" width="30%" align="left">content</th>
</thead>
<tbody><a title="website" href="website">
<td>content</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</a>
</div>
```

Code for the hover effect (would be the same for the row):

```
.table-3 th:hover{
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #0E5278 0%, #0E5278 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0E5278 0%, #0E5278 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0E5278 0%, #0E5278 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0E5278 0%, #0E5278 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0E5278 0%, #0E5278 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #0E5278), color-stop(1, #0E5278) );
    border:1px solid #0E5278;
    font-style:normal;
    text-transform:none;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

What's the code like that is needed to have a hover effect on the whole box (as if it wasn't a header and a row but just one box)?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist.

Comment: share code difficult to understand this way

Comment: please show us the code you've tried or atleast make a fiddle of it, so we can help you better

Comment: I switched to that solution because I first had everything in one box (everything in the header). It wasn't possible to have different font colours and the hover effect still working. If I added a colour (black) to the body text (which I now put in the row), it would stay black even with the hover effect.

Comment: Please edit your post and add the code there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you want, just apply the :hover to table, based on Joe Marie's  answer use the following CSS:

```
thead tr a{
    color: #328EFD;
}

table:hover, table:hover a{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#328EFD;
}

tr a{
    color:#000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

due to your lack of shown information, I am not sure if I get your question right, but kindly give this a shot, here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2wWUN/1/

HTML code:

```
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#">This is the Header</a></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#">some row content</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

CSS code:

```
thead tr{
    color: #328EFD;
}

thead tr:hover a, tr:hover a{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#328EFD;
}

tr{
    color:#000;
}
```

Comment: this is exactely what I did (also see comments above). It would now be great if you mouse-over the header and you have the hover effect on the header, that the mouse-over effect on the body is shown, too, as if it was one box. does this help?